# Prevent SKSpriteNode from bouncing off other SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode that collides and bounces off another SKSpriteNode. What I want is to be able to detect the collision, but not have it bounce off. I want it to bounce off other nodes, but not this one. Is that possible?

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame]; 
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);


self.zone = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Oval.png"];
self.zone.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));  self.zone.xScale = 0.3;
self.zone.yScale = 0.3;

self.zone.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.zone.frame.size.width/2];
self.zone.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0f;
self.zone.physicsBody.density = 0;
self.zone.physicsBody.friction = 0.4f;
self.zone.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = zoneCategory;
self.zone.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;


self.ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Ball.png"];
self.ball.position = CGPointMake(80,0);
self.ball.name = @"BallNode";//how the node is identified later
self.ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.ball.frame.size.width/2];
self.ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0.1f;
self.ball.physicsBody.friction = 0.4f;
self.ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
self.ball.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

I don't want ball and zone to bounce. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

set `collisionBitMask` and `contactTestBitMask` of those two bodies
like:

```
self.zone.collisionBitMask = 0xFFFFFFFF & (~ballCategory);
self.ball.collisionBitMask = 0xFFFFFFFF & (~zoneCategory);
self.zone.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
```

then when contact occurs expect call of `didBeginContact:` in your `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`.
There will be no collsion.

Comment: You should do this instead: self.zone.collisionBitMask &= ~ballCategory;